# Вызов конструктора из класса

Tags: .net, c#

В языке программирования Java конструктор класса из него самого можно вызывать с помощью конструкции:

> this(<список параметров>)

Есть аналог в C#? Заранее спасибо!

*P.S.1: Зачем это нужно? Можно оч. удобно перепрыгивать между конструкторами избегая лишнего кода. В любой момент можно "обнулить" экземпляр вызвав конструктор по-умолчанию.

P.S.2: Создавать отдельную функцию, выполняющую роль конструктора и вызывать ее(как это часто делают в С/С++) не предлагать.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

да, конечно есть:

```
class Territory//Класс описывает логику игры
{
...
//Конструкторы класса
            public Territory(Point size) : this(size.X,size.Y)
            {
            }

            public Territory(int width, int hight)
            {
                _size = new Point(width, hight);
                Clear();
            }
...
}
```

ещё можно добавить пустой конструктор:

```
public Territory() : this(new Point())//или this(0,0)
{
}
```